# windows 10 git shell gitignore and VC.db

Tags: windows, git, shell

the foo.vc.db file is rendering git unusable. I downloaded a gitignore file from
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore  . now it seems to have the right stuff as *.VC.db is there, however when I do git pull I see git is NOT ignoring my foo.VC.db file and the merge fails

Comment: Maybe your  VC.db file is added to git, you can remove it from repo `git rm --cached your.VC.db` with this command file will be keep on your local git.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gitignore files which are already tracked by git you need to remove them from the git cache first and then add them:

```
git rm --cached -r . && git add --all
```